# How to make an input string or integer at java

Tags: java, string, input, integer

my teacher making an input program at java that user could only type number, and I want to try to change the input as a string or both of them.

```
private static int[] queue = new int[5];
private static int counters = 0;

private static boolean queueStorage() {
    if (counters < queue.length) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
private static void createQueue() {
    int loopX = 0;
    int alpha = 0;
    while (loopX == 0) {
        System.out.print("Masukkan Data (angka): ");
        Scanner alphaX = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            alpha = alphaX.nextInt();
            loopX = 1;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Masukan harus berupa Angka!");
            loopX = 0;
        }
    }
    queue[counters] = alpha;
    counters++;
}
```

Comment: Just say alphaX.next(). Then try Integer.parseInt(alpha). If it works, it's an integer. If not, it's a string

Comment: What should be final output type? `Integer` or `String`?

Comment: i wanna make the final output type is string or both of them

Answer (score 0):

## Fetchching one single `String` (from `Scanner`)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.next();
```

## Fetching 10 `String`s in loop (from `Scanner`)

```
// Create array with capacity 10
String[] queue = new String[10];

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int position = 0; position < queue.length; position++) {
    queue[position] = input.next();
}
```

## Fetching 10 `int`s in loop (from `Scanner`)

When there is no way to convert received `String` in to `int`, `position` is decremented so you are not loosing attempt. The table finally contains 10 numbers. Even if incorrect values have been provided in the meantime (readed from `Scanner`) and the user has entered e.g. 14 times.

```
int[] queue = new int[10];
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int position = 0; position < queue.length; position++) {
    String input = scanner.next();
    try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt("input");
        queue[position] = number;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        position--;
    }
}
```

## Convert String in to `int` or `Integer`

To parse `String` in to `int`, you can use:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt("123");
```

or to `Integer`:

```
Integer number = Integer.valueOf("123");
```

In case of any problems (e.g. numer like `12-34`) it throw `NumberFormatException`

Comment: nope otherwise i wanna make variable alpha become  a string

Answer (score -1):

```
private static String[] queue = new String[5];
private static int counters = 0;

private static boolean queueStorage() {
if(counters < queue.length) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

}

private static void createQueue() {

```
int loopX = 0;
String alpha = "";
while(loopX == 0) {
System.out.print("input Data (string):");
Scanner alphaX = new Scanner(System.in);
alpha = alphaX.next();
loopX = 1;
}
queue[counters] = alpha;
counters++;
}
```